# How to verify that serialized JSON is correct in Python/C# in a unit test?

Tags: c#, python, json, serialization, servicestack

I'm writing some code that will serialize a C# object to JSON, send it over the wire and deserialize the JSON to a Python object.

The reverse will also be done, i.e. serialize a Python object to JSON, send it over the wire and deserialize the JSON to a C# object.

On the C# side, I use the ServiceStack JSON libraries. In Python, I'm using the built-in json libraries. The C# library can be changed easily if necessary, the Python one far less so.

```
// C#
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var json = serializer.SerializeToString(request);

// Python
// JsonCodec inherits from JSONEncoder and hooks to 'default' and just 
// returns obj.__dict__ where obj is the object to be serialized
actualSerializedResponse = JsonCodec().encode(response)
```

I've written a unit test in C# to verify that the ServiceStack serialized JSON is as expected by the Python side. In the test, an instance of Foo is created, populated with some hardcoded values, then serialized. To ensure validity, I compare the serialized JSON to some JSON saved in a file, where the contents of the file represent what the Python side expects.

Similarly, there's a unit test in Python to verify that the built-in json library's serialized JSON is as expected by the C# side. Again, to ensure validity, I compare the actual serialized JSON to some JSON saved in a file.

In both cases, the fact that I'm comparing the serialized JSON to some JSON saved in a file implies that the order in which properties are serialized to JSON must be consistent every time and every where the tests are run.

My questions:

- In the C# unit test, it seems that the order of the properties in the JSON match the order in which the properties were defined in the C# class whose instance is being serialized. Can this be relied on?
- In the Python unit test, the order of the properties is consistent but arbitrary. This makes sense since it relies on **dict** and the Python dictionaries are unordered. But can this be relied every time/where?
- Is there a better way to do all this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Python side: you can pass the JSON decoder an option to use an "ordered dictionary" (requires python 2.7 however):

from http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load:

> object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of object_pairs_hook will be used instead of the dict. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example, collections.OrderedDict() will remember the order of insertion). If object_hook is also defined, the object_pairs_hook takes priority.

Comment: This is pretty good - unfortunately, we use Python 2.6 and this is something I definitely can't change. Also, it's worth pointing out that though the unit tests may be in jeopardy (because I compare the actual serialized output to a string whose order is fixed), I think that in actual usage, order is not an issue. Therefore, it would be nice if I didn't have to modify the decode implementation *just* to make a test pass every when/where. I do realize it's probably impossible to avoid that though...

Answer (score 1):

Your first two questions are easy to address. You should not rely on undocumented, implementation specific behavior whenever you can avoid it. I think you can avoid doing so here. To flesh out this answer a bit more, I'll spend some time on your last question.

> Is there a better way to do all this?

The first step is recognizing that what you've currently written are [not unit tests](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923).

Specifically:

> A test is not a unit test if:
>
> - It communicates across the network
> - It touches the file system

Your tests are doing both of these. That's not to say that your tests aren't worth anything, but it's important to note that they are not unit tests. The level that these tests are working at is [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). Integration testing is:

> The phase in software testing in which individual software modules are
>   combined and tested as a group. It occurs after unit testing and
>   before validation testing

I think your problem is that you're trying to mix the tasks of integration and unit testing.

When writing your unit tests you want each test to rely on as few components as possible, and address as specific of a case as possible. In your case, that would mean tests in both C# and Python, neither of which rely on output from the other. In both programs, have your serialization code work on the simplest cases you require it to work for, and validate that you get the JSON loading/dumping that you want. This could mean hand writing JSON as strings in your unit testing code (you want your tests to be small enough that this wouldn't be a pain).

For your integration tests, you just want to check that nothing blows up when your different pieces talk to each other. Here, you don't have to worry that the serialization and reading is correct, since you've already covered that with your unit tests. If they talk well, great!

Then, if you run in to bugs, fix them and document them with an appropriate test case. In the end you should have *lots* of *little* unit tests and a *few* slightly bigger integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some clarification follows. I'm aware I shouldn't rely on undocumented behaviour where I can avoid it. Hence, my third question about a better way to do this. Also, I'd like to clarify that my unit test does *not* communicate across the network. In fact, I think it does what you suggested, except that it reads the expected result from a file rather than storing it as a hard-coded string in the test. I've edited my question above - hopefully, it's clearer.

Comment: Is it actually important for your software (not just your unit tests) that the objects are in the same order every time? If so Stefaan suggests a possible solution. If not, I would argue that your unit tests are not small enough.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to Stefaan below - no. It's only the unit tests that are at stake here. How can I make them smaller then they are now?

Comment: Well, it could be as easy as serializing smaller objects. Can you create a minimal object that doesn't have this issue? Getting to a point where you could do this could involve creating mock objects (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to get things down to size. You want to make sure that you're *only* testing serialization, and only one part of serialization at a time.